# Adding more than one contact in FGDC compliant metadata?

Tags: metadata, arccatalog

I am new to following the FGDC metadata standards. I have received an SDSFIE compliant geodatabase. My job is to build on this Geodatabase.

Each feature class already has FGDC compliant metadata. As I am adding to feature classes I would like to update the contact information to include both my name/contact and also maintain the name/contract of the previous person who worked on this Geodatabase.

When I go into editing mode via ArcCatalog working on stylesheet FGDC ESRI I have found the `"identification"` and `"contact"` tabs. I don't see where I can add an additional Person as a contact.

Is this possible? If so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The FGDC specification doesn't allow for multiple contacts, and would invalidate the document, unfortunately. You can add additional contacts and customize the schema that you validate against, or easier yet, figure out a way to jigger the fields within 'Point of Contact' to fit your use-case: perhaps you can change the 'type' to "Organization", provide detailed instructions within "Contact Instructions" and include the other contacts information as additional phone/email/address fields?